# Jump from a TableViewCell to a ViewController embedded in a NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

I am a newbie in iOS development and I am creating an application that has a sidebar, and from this sidebar the user can select a View to jump to. The views that are offered are part of a navigation controller. The NavigationController is the front of a revealViewController, so the sidebar will appear in every window linked to the NavigationController.

Bellow you can see my storyboard.

[image: Main Storyboard]
The problem is, if I click the Map("Mapa") item from the menu(sidebar) I will have to move to the second View from the navigationController. If I use a regular segue the navigation properties will disappear. Is there a way to move to any of the views and maintain the navigation hierarchy?

Thanks in advance,

Caio Guedes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to have a sidebar in every view and just switch between them. Since you want the views to be separate I would consider using Tab Bar because it is the default option in iOS to navigate between different views and is recommended by Apple. 
But if you want to use sidebar anyways I would recommend using different navigation controller for each view controller. Using one navigation controller would cause too much trouble. Check out this tutorial that I managed to find. http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/
Hope I could help just a little and sorry if I mislead you in any way, I'm a newbie as well!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The application will be developed for iOS and Android, because of that the designers want a sidebar :( but I do think the Tab bar is much better. And yes, I know I can use separate Navigation Controllers and I think that's what I will be doing if the solution I am looking for is too complex. Thank you very much for the link I will have a look at it.

Comment: Actually a few days ago the official guidelines for Android recommend tab bar as well! But if the designers want the sidebar than there's nothing to talk about.